# Javascript use mouseMove event to move objects does not work when mouse suddenly moves quick

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop, svelte

I'm trying to build a drag and drop feature for shapes in a svg using svelte framework. Here is the structure of the svg

```
<svg>
  <g
    on:mousedown={mouseDownHandler}
    on:mousemove={mouseMoveHandler}
    on:mouseup={mouseUpHandler}>
    <circle />
  </g>
```

But with this structure, if I move the mouse quickly, it could accidentally move out of the `<g>` before it can be updated with the current mouse location, and the mouseMoveHandler will stop responding.

I tried something like memorizing the selected element in mouseDownHandler, hoping that even if the mouse is no longer within the group, it could still use the current mouse location to move. But it did not work as I expected.

I suspect that this mouseMoveHandler is only activated while the mouse is within the group, is it correct? Any suggestions for how to overcome this problem?

Thanks

> Update:
>   I am aware that adding the handlers to the parent group would solve the problem. The reason why I wish to do so is because there are different types of elements, and I would like to do different things with them. Right now I have everything in one big mouseMoveHandler under the svg and everything works fine, but it's getting really ugly as I add more features to the handler. This is why I wish to have different handlers for different elements.

Comment: Doesn't feel worth the answer - but putting the mousemove/mouseup on the outer container would allow you to handle these cases where the mouse events may not fire from the component itself reliably.

Comment: > I suspect that this mouseMoveHandler is only activated while the mouse is within the group, is it correct?
  Yes

> Any suggestions for how to overcome this problem?
Can you show example in fiddle? How many elements inside your 'g'?
Maybe try to use more smaller 'g' inside main 'g'

Comment: I understand that you are applying the mousemove to the group? If so apply it to the svg element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're implementing drag and drop (in any situation, not just Svelte or SVG), never apply the 'move' handler to the element itself. Always apply it (and the 'up' handler) to `window`. The 'down' handler should be responsible for noting the start coordinates and registering the 'move'/'up' handlers, nothing more.